# Can't get email field with facebook Javascript SDK v2.5

Tags: javascript, facebook

I know that there are lot similar questions, but i just ca't get it to work.
I managed to get id, name, gender..etc. but now the email.

Here's my code:

```
$(function() {
    FB.init({
        appId  : '1674500109440719',
        status : true, // check login status
        cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    document.getElementById('fb-login').onclick = function() {
        var cb = function(response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                getCurrentUserInfo();

            }
        };
        FB.login(cb, { scope: 'email' });
    };

    function getCurrentUserInfo() {
        FB.api(
            "/me?fields=name,email", {fields: 'gender, first_name, last_name, email'},
            function (response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    id=response.id;
                }
            }
        );

    }
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: why are you using the fields 2 times? just use "/me" and add the fields only with the object. anyway, does the user account even have an email?

Comment: try with multiple Facebook accounts, maybe the one you are testing against has their email set to private.

Comment: That was final thing that i tried, and my mail is public